# Merge three lists together so that each nth item corresponds to the other lists' nth item

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have three lists. I need to make a master list so that.

```
l_site = [www.example.com, www.example.com] 
l_overall = [3.5, 4.5]
l_workload= [4.5, 6.5]
master_list= {[www.example.com, 3.5, 4.5], [www.example.com, 4.5, 6.5]
```

All lists are of the same length. I need this `master_list` so that I can reference it later.

```
def make_master_list(site, overall, workload):
# connect three values with eachother in a list

master_list= {[www.example.com, 3.5, 4.5], [www.example.com, 4.5, 6.5]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The magic you want is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip):

```
l_site = ['www.example.com', 'www.example.com'] 
l_overall = [3.5, 4.5]
l_workload= [4.5, 6.5]

list(zip(l_site, l_overall, l_workload))
```